# JViewLegacy::getForm method works fine in admin component, no method found in front-end

Tags: custom-component

I am facing some strange issue. I have the similar setup for my component on both front-end and back-end component. Here is my view class signature.

```
MyComponentViewForm extends JViewLegacy
```

Now in my view.html.php, I var_dump `$this->getForm()`,

- Works fine and dumps the object from the admin component view class
- `Fatal error: Call to undefined method` error in front-end view class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the full error message with the method and variable info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how much this is correct but I solved this issue by adding a proxy method in my view.html.php:

```
public function getForm()
{
    if (!is_object($this->form))
    {
        $this->form = $this->get('Form');
    }

    return $this->form;
}
```

I am not sure why the view class is calling getForm method of view instead of model. This is still an unknown question to me. Strange part is `$this->get('Form')` inside this proxy method again invoke method in the model. If anyone has any better solution please let me know, I hate these hacks.

Answer (score 1):

it not because the problem in your View.
You need make sure that your Model extend the `JModelForm` (or `JModelAdmin`) and implement method `getForm`:

```
YourComponentModelForm extends JModelForm
{
    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
    {
        $form = $this->loadForm('com_yourcomponent.formname', 'formname', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
        if (empty($form))
        {
           return false;
        }
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: My model extends from `JModelAdmin`. So that shouldn't be the issue. Infact the `JViewLegacy` itself has `getForm` method, so I am wondering how that is not being found on front-end.

Comment: make sure you have front-end model also